# Ajax sempre retorna erro HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, ajax

Utilizo ASP.NET MVC 5 e desenvolvi um site, quando executo a seguinte requisição Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "/Galeria/AddGaleriaItem",
    data: { ID: galeriaID , ObjectString: JSON.stringify(obj) },
    dataType: "json"
})
```

Está tudo configurado certinho, porém quando é executado, a Action NUNCA é chamada...

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddGaleriaItem(string ID, string ObjectString)
{
    ImageIndexer image = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ImageIndexer>(ObjectString);
    TempData["idImageAdded"] = image.Code; 
    return Json(new { response = GaleriaCookieController.AddItem(image, ID).Successful });
}
```

`AddGaleriaItem` está dentro do Controller `Galeria`, mas eu sempre recebo `status: 404` e `statusText: "Not Found"`: segue print do erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Recebo também uma mensagem via HTML assim :

> HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found
>
> O módulo de filtragem de solicitação está configurado para negar uma
>   solicitação quando a cadeia de caracteres de consulta for muito longa.

EDIT: Testei diminuindo o `ObjectString`, mas mesmo assim continua dando erro 404... Só funcionou se eu trocar POST para GET tanto no Ajax quanto no Controller.

Comment: Acredito que o seu objectstring está muito longo. Veja se isto ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42370663/9259549

Comment: @LeonardoL diminui o tamanho do objectstring e continua dando not found... ai eu troquei a Action de POST para GET e funcionou, mas não gostaria que fosse GET.

Comment: Tive esse erro uma vez, parece que é o tamanho da Url. Dá uma olhada nesse artigo, à época me ajudou [HTTP Error 404.15 - query url too long](https://forums.asp.net/t/2024846.aspx?HTTP%20Error%20404%2015%20query%20url%20too%20long)

Comment: Se o Id pertencer ao objeto que está sendo serializado então mude a assinatura do método no c# para receber o apenas objeto já com o tipo definido, com a propriedade Id populada, mude também a forma como está sendo enviada a requisição para `data: JSON.stringfy(obj)`